# Write xml file output values to a dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, linq-to-xml

This code is programmed to display some data values from alot of xml files is their anyway to alter it so that it write the values to a dataset/table?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*");
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            var query = from x in doc.Descendants("XAxisCalib")
                        select new
                       {
                            //Max1 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,
                            //Min2 = x.Attribute("Min").Value


                            MaxChild = x.Descendants("Max"),
                            MinChild = x.Descendants("Min")
                        };

            foreach (var x in query)
            {
                foreach (var nextLevel in x.MaxChild)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("XMax: " + nextLevel.Value);
                }
                foreach (var nextLevel in x.MinChild)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("XMin: " + nextLevel.Value);
                }
                //Console.WriteLine("XAxisCalib");
            }



            var query2 = from y in doc.Descendants("YAxisCalib")

                         select new
                         {

                             //Max3 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,

                             //Min4 = x.Attribute("Min").Value

                             MaxChild = y.Descendants("Max"),
                             MinChild = y.Descendants("Min")

                         };


            foreach (var y in query2)
            {
                foreach (var nextLevel in y.MaxChild)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YMax: " + nextLevel.Value);
                }
                foreach (var nextLevel in y.MinChild)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("YMin: " + nextLevel.Value);
                }

                //Console.WriteLine("YAxisCalib");



                var query3 = from z in doc.Descendants("ZAxisCalib")

                             select new
                             {

                                 //Max5 = x.Attribute("Max").Value,

                                 //Min6 = x.Attribute("Min").Value

                                 MaxChild = z.Descendants("Max"),
                                 MinChild = z.Descendants("Min")
                             };

                foreach (var z in query3)
                {
                    foreach (var nextLevel in z.MaxChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ZMax: " + nextLevel.Value);
                    }
                    foreach (var nextLevel in z.MinChild)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ZMin: " + nextLevel.Value);
                    }

                    //Console.WriteLine("ZAxisCalib");

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm missing something, but what about the DataSet.ReadXml method?:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("myxmlfile.xml");
```

The `ReadXml()` method has an overload for passing in `XmlReadMode`, which provides various options handling the schema.

In your case, assuming that you want to read each XML file into it's own DataSet, you can do something like this:

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*"); 
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) 
{ 
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
}
```

To read the XML files into the same DataSet, you can do something like this:

```
DataSet masterSet = new DataSet();

string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*"); 
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) 
{ 
    //initialize a new dataset and read the xml into it
    DataSet tempSet = new DataSet();
    tempSet.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

    //merge the tables from the temporary datset into the master dataset
    foreach (DataTable table in tempSet.Tables)
        masterSet.Merge(table);        
}
```

Here's another way of doing the same thing, using the enumerable LINQ methods:

```
DataSet masterSet = new DataSet();

string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Sciclone UAC", "*.cfg*"); 
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries) 
{ 
    //initialize a new dataset and read the xml into it
    DataSet tempSet = new DataSet();
    tempSet.ReadXml(fileName, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);

    //merge the tables from the temporary datset into the master dataset
    tempSet.Tables.Cast<DataTable>().ToList().ForEach(table => masterSet.Merge(table));  
}
```

One of the `XmlReadMode` enumerations should definitely suit your needs.

- Auto
- DiffGram
- Fragment
- IgnoreSchema
- InferSchema
- InferTypedSchema
- ReadSchema

Here is a link on MSDN that explains what the different XmlReadMode enumerations do:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlreadmode.aspx

Comment: I want to read only the data I'm extracting out of the xml files to a dataset.

Comment: That's what this does. It reads the data from the XML file into the DataSet.

Comment: So in my code above I have it writing to the console. I want to save it to a dataset instead. So do I take console.writeline out and replace with your code?

Comment: I actually want to read all the xml file values into the same dataset

Comment: @Casey: See edited answer for merging XML files into one DataSet.

Comment: Your code looks great thank you what I don't get/dnon't see is how my data Max/Min of each of the conditions is actually writing to the child dataset to be binded to the master set. Cause I'm not writing the whole xml to it just a few values in each.

Comment: @Casey: Looking at your code it appears the min/max constraints are defined in the XML file. The constraints should be included depending on which XmlReadMode is specified.

Comment: I appreciate your help so much but I think this is still alittle over my head that I'm not understanding how the 'in my example' the XMax and Min values are written to the temp dataset which then are bound to the master. The max and min values are in the xml files and i want to write all of those to one dataset. I guess more once I declare in the code to "select" the max and min out how do i write it to the dataset.

Comment: @Casey: I would suggest that you try it and see what happens.

Comment: I placed the code in their and it builds no errors but it looks like its still writing it to the console. How will the dataset look as an output?

Comment: My code will not write to the console. You probably have Console.WriteLine methods in your code. What are you trying to do with the DataSet once it's populated?

Comment: i think that where I'm confused so in my code I take out the console.writeline statements do i replace them with anything?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. What should happen after the DataSet is loaded?

Comment: after i write the values to dataset i need to write them to an excel spreadsheet.